# sass - how can I watch for changes on a folder, and, if it changed, compile a sass file ouside of it?

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

Well, basically is what the title says.
I have a sass structure in wich I have a folder containing Ionic scss files, and a parent scss file containing some variables.
I'd need to compile the ionic scss files when the parent file is modified.
Is there a way to listen to one file's changes and, if it changed, compile another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import all your scss using `@import` in another scss file (let's say your main.scss) then watch the main.scss file. Any changes that you make on any of the files included will be compiled to your config file

or you want separate compiled files?